# Angular - the specified Date value does not conform to the required format

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to convert a date to specific format (`dd/MM/yyyy`) , so i created the below pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormat',
})
export class DateFormat implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
        var datePipe = new DatePipe("fr-FR");
        return datePipe.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    }
}
```

when i use it like this

```
this.editOrganizationForm.patchValue({
    startDate: this.dateFormat.transform(organization.effectiveDate.startDate);
})
```

is show the below working

> The specified value "02/05/1999" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: it seems your value "02/05/1999" is already in the dd/MM/yyyy format, do you want the pipe not to change it if the case?

Comment: where are you using `yyyy-MM-dd`, your date appears in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Comment: @Kaddath  the value of `organization.effectiveDate.startDate` it's `1999-05-02T09:15:30Z`

Comment: Well, it's not what your error says.. not trying to doubt your word, but what do you get if you log `value` in the transform function? We can't help you without consistent informations

Comment: What is the form control behind `editOrganizationForm` ? If it's an input of type date, your issue might be that you are providing a date in the wrong format to the `patchValue`.

Answer (score 2):

> The specified value "02/05/1999" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

you return date in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'

> return datePipe.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

why not

```
return datePipe.transform(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```